# In the Win64 ABI, can the reserved argument stack space be used for general purpose storage?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, calling-convention, win64, abi

I'm learning x64 assembly on Windows for 'fun'. The [MSDN documentation for the x64 calling convention on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) says:

> The caller is responsible for allocating space for parameters to the callee, and must always allocate sufficient space for the 4 register parameters, even if the callee doesn’t have that many parameters. This aids in the simplicity of supporting C unprototyped functions, and vararg C/C++ functions.

As my functions are not C unprototyped functions or varargs C/C++ functions, does this mean I can always use `[rsp+8]` to `[rsp+32]` (assuming an unmodified value of `rsp` right after a call) for general purpose storage within my function, like for local variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use inbound parameter scratch space for any purpose. But you knew this already: Permission to do this is already implied by the legality of modifying inbound parameters.

```
void somefunction(int arg1)
{
    arg1 = anyvalue; // mov [rsp+8], anyvalue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. However modifying inbound parameters would rather be `mov rcx, anyvalue` as the argument is passed via `rcx`, which is why I was unsure about `[rsp+8]`.

Comment: But you're also permitted to spill inbound parameters. That's why the reserved space is there, after all. `void somefunction(int arg1) { /* spill: mov [rsp+8], rcx */ arg1 = anyvalue; /* mov [rsp+8], anyvalue */ }`

Answer (score 1):

I think what he is trying to do is more something like this:

```
*(decltype(&anyvalue))((PBYTE)&arg1+8) = anyvalue; // mov [rsp+8+8], anyvalue
```

As far as I understand, Microsoft states that you are required to allocate enough space for the callee to store four registers (rcx, rdx, r8. r9), even in a function that takes only one argument (in rcx).

Note: i'm sorry about the ugly c code and the old-school casting mixed with the new decltype keyword